# Is it possible to find if the connection has been established in active mq in c#

Tags: c#, jms, activemq-classic

Here is my code

```
    private Connection _connection;

    private ISession _session;

    private const String QUEUE_DESTINATION = "DotNet.ActiveMQ.Test.Topic";

    ConnectionFactory factory;        

    Transpo

    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        factory = new ConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

        _connection = factory.CreateConnection("system", "manager") as Connection;

        bool x=_connection.TransportFailed;

        _connection.ClientId = "LFV";//Exception when connection not estab

        _connection.Start();//Exception when connection not estab

        _session = _connection.CreateSession();
    }
```

I get an exception at _connection.ClientId and  _connection.Start. Is there any way i can avoid this exception by finding if the connection has been established or not before calling the start method and assigning the client ID.

Comment: What is the exception you get?
Your clientId must be unique (the exception you get is probably related to that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not setting a unique client ID then the exception would be expected as only one client can be connected to the broker for any given client Id.  If you fix your code such that each client app has it's own unique client Id then the problem should resolve itself.  You can of course also set an exception listener on the Connection to get notified of errors.

There is no way to test the connection as it's waiting for you to either set a ClientId or start the connection in order to behave as a JMS client.  The actual connection handshake doesn't happen until the start call or any call that would require a fully established connection such as createSession etc.  You should code you application to respond to failures from connection start.

Oh and FYI, setting client ID after calling start will have no effect as it is only allowed prior to the start of the Connection.

Comment: I am using a unique client id. The scenario is if someone tries to connect with an invalid username/password or say the active mq service is down ,i want to know prior to assigning client id that the connection was not established.

Comment: It's been a while since I've last worked with AMQ, so I'm not sure it will work, but you can try to set the clientId after the _connection.Start(); call.
By default, the AMQ will provide a unique client id if not provided prior to the connection.Start, i'm just not sure you can change it after the connection is started.